# Utilizing the belongsTo eloquent relationship with a slug and not the relationship id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Given the following two tables and relationships:

Model Containers: id, name, desc, created_at, updated_at

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Items', 'container_id', 'id');
}
```

Model Items: id, container_id, type_id, name, created_at, updated_at

```
public function containers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Containers', 'id', 'container_id');
}
```

How can I get all `items` belonging to a `container` where all I have is `container:name` without having todo something like:

```
//Route::get('/api/v1/containers/{container}/items', 'ItemsController@index'); 
public function index($container)
{
    //Show all items in a specific container
    return Containers::where('name', $container)
        ->firstOrFail()
        ->items()
        ->get()
        ->toJson();
}
```

...and to view a specific item in a specific container without having todo something even more nasty like:

```
//Route::get('/api/v1/containers/{container}/items/{item}', 'ItemsController@show');
public function show($container, $item)
{
    //Show specific item in a specific container
    return Containers::where('name', $container)
        ->firstOrFail()
        ->items()
        ->where('id', $item)
        ->firstOrFail()
        ->toJson();
}
```

In this case, I only have the container name as its a URL friendly slug and aids in thwarting URL manipulation.

Is there a way to - even if it's a secondary belongsTo relationship - to achieve this by referencing the name of the container so I can just do `Items::find($containerName)` without changing the primaryKey field in the models.

Comment: Try to use `with()`. Just read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#Eager%20Loading%20Multiple%20Relationships) @ironchefbadass

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but I'm here because after reading through the docs it's not evident to me how to solve this. If you care to expand on your answer I'd certainly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to achieve this by doing the inverse of what you have done (calling `Item` rather than `Contractor(s)`. It will look something like this:

```
$items = Item::whereHas(['container' => function($query) use ($container) {
    $query->where('name', $container);
}])->get()->toJson();
```

The `::whereHas()` method will only return `items` which have a `container` with the name you specify.

If this isn't short enough, you can create a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) on your `Item` model, moving the functionality above into it:

```
// App\Item.php - or where the model is
public function scopeInContainer($query, $container, $id = null)
{
    $query = $query->whereHas(['container' => function($q) use ($container) {
        $q->where('name', $name);
    }]);

    if ($id) {
        $query = $query->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
$items = Item::inContainer($container)->get()->toJson();
```

Then when calling the `Item` via `$id`, you would only need to call:

```
$item = Item::find($id);
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: The query scope works fantastically!

The only concern I have with `$item = Item::find($id);` is (unless I'm missing something) you could alter the id number in the URL and see an item not in the container you are looking in -  this is why I wanted to use the reverse relationship to enforce the constraint of item:id in container. Perhaps thats simply another query scope where I pass along the item id along with the zone?

Comment: Apologies I didn't see the restriction required. To answer your question, yes it can be done as a query scope but not necessarily a separate one. I'll update my answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks, I took a stab at it:

    public function scopeInContainer($query, $container, $item)
    {
        if ($item) {
            return $query->whereHas('containers', function ($q) use ($container, $item) {
                $q->where('name', $container)->where('items.id', $item);
            });
        }
        return $query->whereHas('containers', function ($q) use ($container) {
            $q->where('name', $container);
        });
    }

It works but violates DRY which makes my skin crawl

Comment: @ironchefbadass I've updated my answer to meet your "DRY" needs. The `$id` is now an optional argument in the `->inContainer()` query scope.

Comment: This works beautifully - thank you so much. The only edit I had to make was removing "->firstOrFail()" - that ended up returning many more items than just the single item:id passed.